# Command Prompt Runas cscript

Tags: batch-file

I have **get_data.vbs** located in **C:/test/source/**. I've created **run.bat** file in **C:/test/bin**.
I'm able to run vbs script when I put the following in bat file:

**cscript ../source/get_data.vbs**

**Q:** Why it doesn't work when I use runas command:

**runas /user:domain\username "cscript \"../source/get_data.vbs""**

If I put full path, it works without any issues:

**runas /user:domain\username "cscript \"C:/test/source/get_data.vbs""**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because `runas` is started on its current directory `%windir%\System32` and there is no `/source/get_data.vbs` there.
If you want to make sure of this, try this code:

```
start /separate runas /user:domain\username "cscript \"../source/get_data.vbs""
```

You will see on title of the Window that opened something like **C:\Windows\System32**\runas.exe